# How to change case of characters identified via pattern matching in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, pattern-matching

I have several PostgreSQL tables with "comment" columns (data type = text) for which I am trying to standardize the use of upper and lowercase. Specifically, I'd like to change the case of comment strings from all-caps to capitalization of only the first character in each sentence (there are typically 1-3 sentences per comment). I standardized the number of spaces between sentences (to 1) with

```
update table
set comment = regexp_replace(comment, '( ){2,}',' ','g');
```

and set all characters in each string except the first to lower case with

```
update table
set comment = upper(left(comment, 1)) || lower(right(comment, -1))
```

Now, how do I change the case of the first character after each period to uppercase? I can select the relevant characters with

```
select regexp_matches('Testing. this. using. some. text.', '([.]\s\S)', 'g');
```

but haven't been able to figure out how to capitalize these. Also, I'm sure there is a better way to conduct these steps in a more integrative way, but this is my noob-ish attempt.

Comment: What about using `initcap()`?

Comment: Let me suggest that SQL and/or regular expressions are not the appropriate tools for this; in fact it's a bad idea. How do you handle proper names (Roland, George, ...), titles (The Queen of England, The Prime Minister ... ) also country names (United Kingdom or UK,  USA, Japan ...) and how about acronyms (NASA, ISO, ...), non standard words (PosgreSQL), and the list goes on. An entire system could be written for just this and still miss many conditions. You won't need to handle all of them, but can you dismiss any of them? However, But if you are still up for GOOD LUCK!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I looked into INITCAP during my attempts at accomplishing this task and it capitalizes the first letter of each word, not the first letter of each sentence.

Comment: @Belayer: I'm sure you are right that in many situations there are too many conditions that would be missed. However, in my case the comments are generally quite simple and lack proper names, etc. My primary objective is simply  to get rid of all of the uppercase except for the first letter of each sentence. I can accept lowercase applied incorrectly to the few acronyms, etc. that are rarely found in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked in my situation, in which comments are made up of one or more sentences and sentences are separated by a period and single space:

```
with source as (
    select regexp_split_to_table('hello. world', '\.\s') sentence
)
select array_to_string(
    array(
         select upper(left(sentence, 1)) || right(sentence, -1) sentence from source
     ), '. '
) modified_comment;
```